# How to configure Wildfly 8 to target directly the project build path

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, wildfly-8

I got a web project that don't use maven, i remember that i had worked once in a project where the tomcat was targeting the build path where eclipse automatically put the compiled files so we don't need to restart the server all the time to see the changes. There is some way to do this in eclipse + wildfly 8? please, let me know how to found this folder and how to configure wildfly to point directly to it.

Answer (score 0):

Install [JBoss Tools](http://tools.jboss.org) into Eclipse and it will manage this for you.